# What is a word that is a little bit slower than "instantly" but faster than "over time" and "sooner or later"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, vocabulary

I am trying to find a word that can be used in this context and that is a little bit slower than “instantly” but faster than “over time” and “sooner or later”:

> [insert time that is slower than instantly but faster than over time and sooner or later], I am fascinated.

Comment: Soon? Presently? Shortly?

Comment: Gradually, I am becoming fascinated by x.

Answer (score 1):

“momentarily”: means either “at any moment now” or “for a moment”

Per the 3rd definition on the [Merriam-Webster entry for this word](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/momentarily), this means "at any moment : in a moment"

Comment: This site encourages its users to provide research for their questions and answers. Could you find some definitions from known dictionaries that could support your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Not all adverbs of time can go at the beginning of the sentence in the way you have it. The use of the present tense also influences the choice of the adverb (phrase). "For a few moments there, I ***was*** fascinated" sounds more common to my ears. But I guess you can also say

> ***For a few seconds***/***For a few minutes/In passing***, I am fascinated.

[WordHippo](http://For%20a%20short%20time) defines them all as meaning "for a short time or for a limited period of time".

Among the many synonyms you will also find ***briefly*** for example, but rather than at the beginning, it would go better in the middle or at the end:

> I am briefly fascinated/I am fascinated, briefly.